# Is this a safe thing to do?

Tags: php, download, xor

Code first, then an explanation:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_POST['filename']."\"");
$key = md5(rand());
echo $key;
$key = str_repeat($key,ceil(strlen($_POST['data'])/32));
echo $_POST['data'] ^ $key;
?>
```

What this does is allow me to `POST` data through a form (dynamically generated) and have the posted data be downloaded as a file.

I'm using a very basic XOR encryption that puts the (fixed-length, 32-byte) key at that start of the file. The intention is not to secure the data, but rather to obfuscate it.

Having such a file means that potentially anyone could POST whatever data they wanted to it and it would be offered as a download to the user's computer, but I believe a combination of the user having to accept the download, and the data being passed through XOR with a one-time key, is enough to prevent malicious use.

Is there any reason why I should not use such a file? Are there better alternatives to what I'm doing? Is `application/octet-stream` the appropriate MIME-type?

Comment: What is the use of this? If all this does is return the data the user posted right back to the user, what's the opportunity for "malicious use" anyway?

Comment: Passing data to be downloaded to a file. The only usage at present is to download the contents of localStorage as a file so the user can save it, either for backup (before clearing browser files, for example), for changing browsers, or even changing computers entirely.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To produce files of variable sizes?

Comment: You should change the title. It isn't really clear to the people that see it in the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is completely safe from user's perspective - because it makes no sense for user to harm itself and POST cannot be passed by potentially malicious url or redirect. And even if it could - there is just a script that returns a file to download. This cannot harm anyone by definition.

But you should keep in mind that after you sent it to user - you can never trust the data in case that you accept the data to deobfuscate and use in some way.

> Is application/octet-stream the appropriate MIME-type

As long as you return binary data - yes, it is appropriate

Comment: @Ktash: "why" what? It is safe because it is safe. It makes no sense for user to harm himself

Comment: At least having the 'It makes no sense for the user to harm himself' would be helpful. As stated it provides no confidence in a basis on anything. It is just a statement

Comment: "For the URL to be used for different purposes" -- op uses `$_POST`, not `$_GET`. You cannot pass post data via link or redirect

Comment: Yeah, I edited that out. Looked back up at the code. Still possible, but certainly not easy.

Comment: You can pass post data via an auto-submitting form. And I'll only be allowing users access to data they had access to already in other ways (in this case, through the brower's console).

Comment: @Kolink: so you pass it from the auto-submitted form and downloading file window appears. How would it harm anyone?

Comment: I was mainly asking this question in case there was something I had missed, since people seem to be good at spotting things like that here. Anyway, does anyone know the answer to my question about the MIME type?

Comment: @zerkms Auto submitting form from a malicious user. It would require another injection point, but even just overriding the form data on submit to be something malicious. Not impossible, but harder and unlikely. It turns it into an easy way to trick people if it is used often and trusted at face value.

Comment: @Kolink: mime is fine as long as you send binary file